# Touch pad usage will randomly copy-paste text from the screen

Tags: linux, touchpad

Whenever I use the touch pad to scroll with two fingers, some lines of text in the current window are copy-pasted. This happens very rarely (maybe once a week).

I am certain that this is not caused by interaction with the context menu (which provides a copy paste option) because I never see a context window and the mouse cursor had to move very quickly to not notice a quickly disappearing window. Moreover, when I switch to a text box after this happens, the clipboard is still the same as before.

The reason I am blaming the touch pad (driver?) is that I only ever saw the issue when using the touch pad.

I am using Fedora 27 on a P51 Lenovo Think Pad.

Comment: Your touch pad is middle-clicking for some reason.

Comment: That sounds very plausible. Any idea how to specifically disable the middle-click or would that be a bug of the driver?

Comment: If you install `xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-legacy` then you should be able to set the options for the `synaptics(4)` driver via xorg.conf or udev.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564349/392411 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Easiest way is just to disable Tap-to-click under device settings.

Answer (score 14):

Because you say that "it happens very *rarely* (maybe once a week)" when you "scroll with two fingers", I suspect that during those times, you did a three finger tap on the touch pad which (in most cases) is registered as a middle-click causing the contents of the clipboard to be pasted.

You can disable that using the following two steps:

1. **Identify the Touch pad device ID**:

   From a command prompt, enter: `xinput list`

   This should list all the recognized xinput devices with their IDs. Sample output is shown below for reference:

   ```
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Integrated Webcam: Integrated W           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```

   In the above example, the touch pad is `SynPs/2 Synaptics TouchPad` with **`id=15`**.
2. **Disable the middle click action on the touchpad**:

   From a shell/command-prompt enter: `xinput set-button-map 15 1 0 3`

   *Explanation:*
   The format of the above command is:
   `xinput set-button-map <device-id> <left-button-action> <middle-button-action> <right-button-action>`

   In this case, `15` is the ID of the device, and then the 3 numbers following the device ID represents the action for the `left`, `middle` and `right` button on the device in order. By setting action `1` for the `left` button, we are mapping it to the `left click` action. By setting action `0` for the `middle` button, we are disabling it and similarly setting action `3` for the `right` button we are mapping it to the `right click` action.

Hope that solves your problem and others's who end up on this page.

Answer (score 0):

This worked very well for me.
It disables the three fingers paste.

From command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste false
```

To re-enable the functionality:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-enable-primary-paste true
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on a System76 laptop.

Comment: Credits to https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-middle-mouse-button-click-paste-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux